# what is difference between Process Builder And Flow in salesforce

Tags: process-builder, flow

What is the Difference Between Process Builder And Flow .Any One Give Main Differnce.

Comment: @Farook - Seems you are asking a questions that could be answered by reading the official documentation. Please review the documentation and ask question [Ask] that are on topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Builder is the Lightining Process it is advanced Model of Workflow Rule ,But Process Builder is Limited to some Restrictions and Constructions Diagram,But Flow Process is Not Limited Process,we Can Create a Record and update a Record and also Check the Conditon for all types of Records etc ,Flow Process can do in Visual Force Page itself.In process Builder We Run The Apex Classes And Trigger Also

Comment: I Need depth Explination Can U Give Me more Data About Process Builder And Flows . And Send Me Any Link About Process Builder And Flow